# Meet the error : Route not defined error laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException Route
> [user.discounts.show] not defined. (View:
> /var/www/html/resources/views/user/discounts/index.blade.php)

```
public function show($id)
{
    $discount = $this->discountRepository->getDiscountById($id);
    $discount_products = $this->discountRepository->getDiscontProductOnDiscount($id);

    return view('user.discounts.detailDiscount', 
         ['discount_products' => $discount_products, 'discount' => $discount]);
}
```

I created a function show on my controller and return a `view('user.discounts.detailDiscount)` but it has error: route not defined, When I call `{{ route('user.discounts.show', ['id' => $discount->id]) }}` . How can I fix these bugs?

```
Route::middleware('user')->prefix('/user')->name('user.')->group(function () {
   Route::prefix('/discounts')->name('discounts.')->group(function () {
   Route::get('/{id}/details', [DiscountController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `Route::group(...)`? What about running `php artisan route:list` on the command prompt? What's the route name shown there?

Comment: remove the dot from route name `name('user.')` -> `name('user')`  `name('discounts.')` -> `name('discounts')`

Comment: @YazanFouadAldbaisy that's incorrect.